Mocking chakra media queries to be mobile view
I am having some issues mocking media queries for show/hide objects on different sizes.  I have tried a couple of solutions in stack overflow including this one:
Figuring out how to mock the window size changing for a react component test
The tests always seem to render the mobile view:

<Show above="md">
        <ChakraModal isOpen={isOpen} onClose={onClose} {...rest}>
          <ModalOverlay />
          <ModalContent
            {...theme.modal.modalContent}
            borderRadius={theme.br05}
            w={{ base: `calc(100% - 2 * ${theme.space[4]})`, md: "100%" }}
            maxW="xl"
          >
           
            {footerCTAs?.length ? (
              <ModalFooter
                data-testid="modal-footer-desktop"
                justifyContent={footerCtaAlignment}
                display={ctaOrientation === "vertical" ? "inline-grid" : "flex"}
                flexWrap="wrap"
                {...theme.modal.modalFooter}
                gap={2}
              >
                {footerCTAs.map(({ label, onClick, variant }) => (
                  <Button key={label} onClick={onClick} variant={variant} {...isModalButtonFullWidth}>
                    {label}
                  </Button>
                ))}
              </ModalFooter>
            ) : null}
          </ModalContent>
        </ChakraModal>
      </Show>
      <Hide above="md">
        <ChakraDrawer isOpen={isOpen} onClose={onClose} placement={placement} isFullHeight={isFullHeight}>
          <DrawerContent borderTopRadius={theme.br05}>
            <DrawerCloseButton alignSelf="end" position="relative" {...theme.modal.drawerCloseBtn} />
          
            {footerCTAs?.length ? (
              <DrawerFooter
                data-testid="modal-footer-mobile"
                justifyContent={footerCtaAlignment}
                display="flex"
                flexDir="column"
                {...theme.modal.drawerFooter}
                gap={2}
              >
                {footerCTAs.map(({ label, onClick, variant }) => (
                  <Button key={label} onClick={onClick} variant={variant} flexGrow={1} width="100%" h={14}>
                    {label}
                  </Button>
                ))}
              </DrawerFooter>
            ) : null}
          </DrawerContent>
        </ChakraDrawer>
      </Hide>


And here is my test

import React from "react";
import { render } from "@testing-library/react";
import { ChakraProvider,  Show, Hide, useBreakpointValue } from "@chakra-ui/react";
import { useMediaQuery } from '@chakra-ui/react';


Object.defineProperty(window, "matchMedia", {
  writable: true,
  value: jest.fn().mockImplementation((query) => ({
    matches: false,
    media: query,
    onchange: null,
    addListener: jest.fn(),
    addEventListener: jest.fn(),
    removeEventListener: jest.fn(),
    dispatchEvent: jest.fn(),
  })),
});

global.innerWidth= 1200;


jest.mock("@chakra-ui/react", () => {
  // --> Original module
  const originalModule = jest.requireActual("@chakra-ui/react");

  return {
    __esModule: true,
    ...originalModule,
    useMediaQuery: jest.fn()
  };
});



it.only("renders multiple ctas in vertical orientation on desktop", () => {
  (useMediaQuery as jest.Mock).mockReturnValue(false);
  
    const { getByTestId, container } = render(
    <ChakraProvider theme={theme}>

        <Modal {...modalProps} isOpen footerCTAs={submitAndCancelCTAs} ctaOrientation="vertical">
          test
        </Modal>
    </ChakraProvider>
  );
  const modalFooter = getByTestId("modal-footer-desktop");
  expect(modalFooter).toHaveStyle({ display: "inline-grid" });
});


Does anyone have any thoughts on this?
Thanks
